# Generating a date in a particular format using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code that looks like this. I am receiving the values
of year, month and day in form of a string. I will test whether they are not null.

If they are not null I will like to generate a date in this format MMddyyyy from the variables

```
        from datetime import datetime

        year = "2022"
        month = "7"
        day = "15"

        if len(year) and len(month) and len(day):
            print('variables are not empty')
            #prepare = "{month}/{day}/{year}"
            #valueDt = datetime.strptime(prepare,"%m/%d/%Y")
        else:
            print('variables are empty')
```

The solution I have is not working. How can I generate this date?

Comment: You just need to convert the input into `datetime` object like `input_date = datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))` and then you can define output format, in your case it would be `%m%d%Y` so something like this `print(input_date.strftime("%m%d%Y"))`

Comment: The result of the solution you provided is 07152022. How do can get the slashes to show? it should be 07/15/2022

Comment: I formatted it and got it like this and it works. input_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: Well I am glad you figured it out, can you modify the question to say `mm/dd/yyyy` as well and answer it?

Answer (score 1):

It should work without calling `len` as well.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

year = "2022"
month = "7"
day = "15"

if year and month and day:
    print('variables are not empty')
    prepare = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    valueDt = datetime.strftime(prepare, "%m/%d/%Y")
    print(valueDt)
else:
    print('variables are empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, date

year = "2022"
month = "7"
day = "15"

if len(year) and len(month) and len(day):
    print('variables are not empty')
    prepare = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    valueDt = datetime.strftime(prepare, "%m/%d/%Y")
    print(valueDt)
else:
    print('variables are empty')
```